# Java HTML Object

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom, object

I have a little bit complex, dirty html code. Is there a good HTML Parser that i can use the HTML code as a Java Object?

e.g. I want access this Code:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div id='foo'>
     <p id='bar'></p>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

like via DOM:

```
[File/Code].getElementById('foo').appendText('bla');
[File/Code].getElement(Element.DIV).getElement(ELEMENT.P).getValue();
//etc...
```

have somebody an idea?

Or is there DOM in Java ([this does not help :(](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html))?

Greetings

Comment: Take a look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: yes, jsoup is what i searched :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give http://jsoup.org/ a try. It can handle very broken html.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Document document = Jsoup.parse("<html>" +
            "  <body>" +
            "   <div id='foo'>" +
            "     <p id='bar'>TEST</p>" +
            "   </div>" +
            "  </body>" +
            "</html>");

    System.out.println("Add blah to the Element with ID: foo");
    Element foo = document.getElementById("foo");
    foo.appendText("blah");

    System.out.println(document.html());

    System.out.println("Get the content of a div having a p:");
    for (Element div : document.getElementsByTag("div"))
    {
        for (Element p : div.getElementsByTag("p"))
        {
            System.out.println(p.text());
        }

    }
}
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @criztovyl_needs_help do you need more information to accept this answer?

Comment: i accept this answer withou more infomations, using jsoup now :)